# How is the subset of the domain of a function, $\mathcal{X}_c\equiv \{x\in \mathcal{X}: f(x)=c\}$, called?

Tags: functions

Take a function $f: \mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{A}$.

Let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ denote the image set of $f$.

Take $c\in \mathcal{C}$.

Consider the subset $\mathcal{X}_c$ of the domain $\mathcal{X}$ defined as
$$
\mathcal{X}_c\equiv \{x\in \mathcal{X}: f(x)=c\}
$$

What is the technically correct name of $\mathcal{X}_c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a set has the label [fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics)) of $c$ under function $f$.

It seems however that the terminology is also used if $c$ is an element of the codomain of $f$ and not necessarily an element of the image of $f$. So more specifically you could call it a non-empty fiber.

Every function induces partition on its domain. The elements are the non-empty fibers.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse image of $c$,denoted by $f^{-1}(c)$ is defined as $$f^{-1}(c)=\{x|f(x)=c\}$$

The set is also called the pre-image of $c$

Comment: Funny you should choose to just call it “pre-image”, when “fiber” is both more specific and more poetic. Of course, poetry isn’t everyone’s thing, so that probably isn’t a criterion.

Comment: I heard the words  pre-image or inverse image  in calculus and fiber in topology. I like pre-image because it is self explanatory for calculus students.

Comment: Ah, yeah. That’s right. “Fiber” is more common in topology. I hear you.